# why static method of a interface can only accessed through Interface.method() why not through implemented class instance

Tags: java

```
interface A {
public static void print(){
System.out.println("interface A");
}
}

class B  implements A{
public static void main(String[] args){
A obj = new B();
obj.print();  //Not possible.
A.print() ;  // It is fine

}
}
```

Here why i cannot access the interface static method using instance of implemented class?

Comment: Because static methods are not inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can not be overridden because they are not inherited you can understand them as method hiding the same is the case for private methods in a superclass or parent class that are not accessible inside the subclass. Static methods do not need instance to be called upon and they are unique/common property of a class not belong to an instance.

You can implement your own static method in child class that has no relation with the same signature as in the parent class, and in order to call them you need to use the class/interface name where they are declared and call the member.

```
A.print()//Calls static method on Interface A
B.print()//Cannot find static method print in class B
B objectB = new B();
objectB.print()//Cannot find static method print in class B
```